# Websphere application resource

Tags: resources, websphere

How is possible to "ereditate" application resources in web module?
My EAR structure is something like (standard structure I think):

```
EAR
+-----Web Module
+-----EJB Module
+-----Utility JAR Module
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to define resources at application level and use them in every module.
I've tried with this configuration with no success:

application.xml

```
...
<resource-ref>  
   <description>my file properties</description>
    <res-ref-name>url/myUrl</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope> 
</resource-ref>
```

ibm-application-bnd.xml

```
...
<resource-ref name="url/realJndiName" binding-name="url/myUrl" />
```

web module class

```
@WebService
public class MyClass {
     @Resource(name="url/myUrl")
     URL myUrl;

     ....
}
```

But the injection fails.
How should this be done? Of course if I move the resource definition in app.xml (with its bindings) everything works, but then I should move the resource even on ejb-jar.xml for EACH ejb which uses it...

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ibm-application-bnd.xml` is intended for `java:app` and `java:global` references defined in `application.xml`, not references defined anywhere in the application.  That approach works fine if you want to declare a single reference and have all components (servlets, EJBs, etc.) share the same reference.  If you want each component to have a unique reference, then you need to declare the references separately and use per-component bindings in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`, `ibm-web-bnd.xml`, etc.